# Android Studio: Shared Preferences save to file

Tags: android, file, device, preferences, shared

I work on an Android app which is a kind of a poll with `RadioButtons`.
Now will the selected radio button be saved in a `SharedPreference`.

Here my Code:

---

```
public class frage1 extends AppCompatActivity {

public RadioGroup antworten_frage1;
public RadioButton antwort_frage1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_frage1);

    //initialize radio group
    antworten_frage1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_antworten_frage1);
    antworten_frage1.clearCheck();

    //attach CheckedChangeListener to radio group
    antworten_frage1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton antwort_frage1 = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            if(null!=antwort_frage1 && checkedId > -1){
                Toast.makeText(frage1.this, antwort_frage1.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}





//button_zurück
public void select_button_back1(View view)
{

    Toast.makeText(this, "Es geht nicht Zurück. Das ist die erste Frage.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

//button_weiter
public void select_button_go1 (View view)
{
    startActivity(new Intent(frage1.this, frage2.class));

    //write answer

    RadioButton antwort_frage1 = (RadioButton) antworten_frage1.findViewById(antworten_frage1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("antworten", Context.MODE_ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("antwort_frage1",antwort_frage1.getText().toString());


    editor.apply();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Antwort gespeichert", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

---

Now my question: 
How can I save the answer to a file on the device (so that I can read it out later on pc)?

Comment: **1**. Map your answer in json format, write your json in a file and save the file in your internal memory.
**2**. Use a database like **SQLite**.

Answer (score 0):

If you use shared preferences you write data to a private xml file. So your file is already on the device. A file explorer cannot find and show your files as they are private. You could copy that xml file to external memory though.